# Como obtener un dato de un array que esta dentro de otro array Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener el resultado de val del array optionsForos para que lo muestre en un list, pero no se como entrar hasta val.

Estoy utilizando esta sentencia para entrar al nombre y ya lo tengo pero no funciona para val

```html
this.datos.nombre.optionsForos.val
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `this.datos[0].optionsForos.forEach(item => console.log(item.val, item.label));`

Comment: Gracias, me marca esto: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes de `console.log(this.datos);`?

Comment: Me muestra todo el array, como esta en la imagen

Comment: Cópialo y pégalo en la pregunta, como texto no como imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que muestras en el log, puedes mostrar una lista usando:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of datos[0][0].optionsForos">{{item.val}}</li>
```